# AHK sending a key held in a variable "down"

Tags: autohotkey

I want to send a key which is held in a variable down. The reason it is held in a variable is because I use a gui for the user to input the key in question.

Currently this works:

```
Send %hotkey%
```

But this doesn't:

```
Send {%hotkey% down}
```

How can I make this work properly?

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

**Version 1:**

```
hotkey := "n"
Send {%hotkey% down}
```

**Version 2:**

```
!^z::
    hotkey := "n"
    Send {%hotkey% down}
return
```

Make sure that `n` is enclosed in `""`. Enclosing any text with `""` means that you are assigning it as a text string. And variable used in a `Send` command should contain a text string.

Comment: Nope this doesnt work. I have replied on ahkscript also http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5105

Comment: @PaulChambers Check **Version 2** in notepad. Hotkey is CTRL+ALT+z . Does it works in notepad? For me both versions are working. I think you are having problem with application where you use that script, not with script itself.

Comment: @PaulChambers I think that your problem is related with this: http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm#Repeating__or_Holding_Down_a_Key

Comment: How send as key, not text?

Comment: @nim Send command sends simulated keystrokes and mouse clicks to the active window. It does not send text by itself. More about Send command here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

Answer (score 0):

This works in AutoHotKey V2:

```
key := "a"

downtext := "{" . key . " down}"
uptext := "{" . key . " up}"

Send downtext ;sends key down
Send uptext ;sends key up
```